# Visual Studio keeps asking for Python source file when running a Python extension project

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, tensorflow

I use Python3.6 Generate tensorflow's Faster-RCNN's (on github: https://github.com/dBeker/Faster-RCNN-TensorFlow-Python3.5 ) .pb file and run this .pb file OK with Python3.6.

I also write an MFC program (Win10 + VS2015 + C++ + Tensorflow1.8 both GPU and CPU version) to read and test this .pb file, but when I run the code :

```
m_session->Run({ { strParaName1, m_TensorInput[0] },
                 { strParaName2, data_ } },
               { opName1, opName2, opName3, opName4 },
               {},
               &m_TensorOutput).ok())
```

MFC pop up a dialog box that says it needs `pystate.c` and suggests some bogues path:

[image: asking for path]

I downloaded a "pystate.c" file from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pystate.c . When I select it, MFC shows error as below:

> Module: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python36.dll
>
> The source file is different from the file when the module was
>   generated. Do you want the debugger to use it?

When I choose "yes", I get the source with an error message, as shown below:

[image: error in VS]

I guess this pystate.c is py2.7's version, my python version is 3.6, so this file may not be suitable.

Comment: I uninstall Anaconda3 and Anaconda3 'phthon3.6.5, and then I install python from : python.org/downloads/release/python-365 python-amd64.exe, and download the python3.6.5 's barball. But the error in the last picture still appears ：" interp is nullptr ".  I think this time the pystate.c is suit python36.dll, but there are other unknown errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio's debugger is going to examine Python's source code for whatever reason (from what I can see, some C-level error occurs) and is asking for its location.

To provide it, you need to get the source *exactly equivalent to whatever your copy of Python was made from.* The bogus path that the dialog provides by default is the path saved inside the executable. This is where the sources were on the build machine where and when your copy of Python was built.

Anaconda apparently can't be bothered to provide the corresponding sources for their binary packages (a trait shared by many private packaging ecosystems; for software covered by (L)GPL, this is a license violation, but Python's license allows that), leaving you on your own here.

Fortunately, Python leaves some pointers in its executable on which sources you need. E.g., for Anaconda's Python 3.6.5:

```
>>> import sys, platform

>>> sys.version
'3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64-bit (AMD64)]'

>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

>>> platform.python_revision()
''
```

So, this is 3.6.5 release, and since there's no `revision`, it was probably built from the official tarball (let's hope they didn't apply any private patches -- otherwise, you're out of luck).

So, download the tarball (for 3.6.5, it's at https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/ , under the "Gzipped source tarball" entry), unpack it somewhere and point VS to the corresponding file in the resulting tree. After a few times, it should start to pick up further files automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me ! You said all rigth, my Anaconda3-python is 3.6.5 version, I uninstall Anaconda3 and Anaconda3 'phthon3.6.5, and then I install python from : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/ python-amd64.exe.  The error in the last picture still appears ：" interp is nullptr ", I think this time the pystate.c is suit python36.dll, but there are other unknown errors.

Comment: @EdwardMa Why that error occurs is a completely different matter. Please ask it as a separate question. In it, for us to be able to help you, be sure to provide the information specified in [ask], including a [mcve].